# django-leaflet installation exception

Tags: python, django, leaflet

I'm new to Django and I would like to install leaflet to show the map. I've followed the [installation instructions](https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), and while the pip command seemed to work well, when I go to settings.py to add leaflet to my installed apps, when I save the file I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000002494D622730>
```

At the end of the traceback there is this:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

In the installed apps section of settings.py I've tried adding 'leaflet' or 'django-leaflet'. What am I missing?

Comment: Post the complete traceback

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have GDAL installed properly.  This is a geodjango requirement, [see the installation notes.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/)